# functional programming in php

Tags: php, functional-programming

So I've been writing this class in php (first timer) that has a function that returns a function based on a parameter and it looks something like this:

```
$f=function($a){
    return function($b){
        return $a.$b;
    };
};

echo $f('a')('b');
```

but I can't figure out why it doesn't do what I want. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Basically I need to write a function that takes a string ($type) and writes a function that takes some other strings and turns them into a html input like so:

```
public static function InputFormat($t){
    return function ($f, $p, $e){
        return 
            "<div class='inputformat' id='".$f."'>".
                "<ul>".
                    "<li id='namefield'>".$f."</li>".
                    "<li id='input'><input name='".$f."' type='".$t."' value='".$p."'></li>".
                    "<li id='error'>".$e."</li>".
                "<ul>".
            "</div>";
    };
}
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't have a `$a` parameter for one - which one should it be?

Comment: Where are the additional params taken from?

Comment: The example code at the bottom is pointless - why return a function when it could directly return what the inner function returns? Just change `InputFormat($t)` to `InputFormat($t,$f,$p,$e)`

Comment: Sorry, I accidnetally put $b instead of $a in the higher function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your function does not look good.

**You function should look so:**

```
$f = function($a){
   return function ($a) use ($b) {
            return $a.$b;
         };
};
```

Second: you can't call your function like **$f('a')('b');**. **You call your function this way**:

```
$f2 = $f('a');
echo $f2('b');
```

This is how closure work in php!

I hope this will help you. Ask me if you have questions.

Comment: You'll get an `Undefined variable: b` on this example. Kindly correct your code.